# Volume down no longer silents call

Tags: volume-control, lg-g3, volume-buttons

On my LG G3, the volume down button no longer silent incoming calls for some reason. Does anyone know how to re-enable it?

Comment: @beeshyams It's very strange that the volume down key suddenly answers calls rather than silencing them.

Comment: @beeshyams Really? All of my other phones silent the ringtone on incoming calls with the volume down key as well. How does yours do it then?